# Is there a way to get the file metadata (namley width, height and frame rate) of all the video files in a folder automatically in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, cmd.exe, automation, metadata

basically I have 1,000 or so video files in a folder and want to get their

1. Frame Rates
2. Height
3. Width

in a text file. Is it possible using wmic or ffmpeg or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/), you could run this command:
`exiftool -ImageWidth -ImageHeight -VideoFrameRate /path/to/files/ >Listing.txt`

Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.